# how to add duplicate record with just one change and other field is zero in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have product table in that table I have insert (productid,size,qty,price) using insert query

```
$dataspec1 =array(
        'pid'=>$pid,
        'size'=>$size,
        'price'=>$price,
        'qty'=>$Qty

                );
$db->insert('tbl_product_view',$dataspec1);
```

Now I want insert duplicate record in table of same productid with some-change
I want to insert 2 record just size in change and other filed is 0

For example
**first record :- 1,S,1200,12**
Now I want to second record as follow
**second record :- 1,M,0,0**

I have also size table available
Can u help me please

Thanks

Comment: only S,M sizes are available or more variant are there

Comment: this size i get form tbl_size its M,S,L

Comment: then how to guess what size is next or it is like s-m,m-l,l-s

Comment: i have tbl_size table can i loop that one before insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a new table that will hold off all your variants that is related with your products.

Like variants - >

```
              vid -> INT -> PKEY
              PID -> INT -> Reference to your product ID
              Variant Title -> Varchar -> here is the size will be going
              Variant Value -> Varchar -> Here S,M,X,XL etc will be going.
```

Hope I am clear enough to explain you...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you want. If you want to insert 2 sets of data, you have probably to make 2 inserts. Depends on how your underlying class is built, what isn't obvious in your code.

```
$dataspec1 = array('pid'=> $pid,
                'size'=> 'S',
                'price'=> 1200,
                'qty'=> 12
);
$dataspec2 = array('pid'=> $pid,
                'size'=> 'M',
                'price'=> 0,
                'qty'=> 0
);
$db->insert('tbl_product_view', $dataspec1);
$db->insert('tbl_product_view', $dataspec2);
```

But maybe your class can cope with multiple inserts at once. Hard to tell without seeing it. On the other hand, be sure that pid isn't a primary key in your database table or you won't be able to insert 2 records with the same pid (1).

Comment: pid is not primary key and when i insert data is just like 1,M,1200,12 now i want add duplicate record as 1,S,0,0

Comment: If you want to add a duplicate record, you need to insert it explicitly.